# Parsing json array returns `Expected a value of type 'List<>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: dart

Im trying to parse the the following json and map it to equivalent objects:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Will Everett",
      "golfers":[
         {
            "name":"Bryson DeChambeau",
            "rounds":[
               {
                  "number":1,
                  "score":"75"
               }
            ],
            "today":"-",
            "thru":"7:41 PM"
         },
         {
            "name":"Shane Lowry",
            "rounds":[
               {
                  "number":1,
                  "score":"75"
               },
               {
                  "number":2,
                  "score":"--"
               }
            ],
            "today":"-",
            "thru":"7:41 PM"
         },
         {
            "name":"Gary Woodland",
            "rounds":[
               {
                  "number":1,
                  "score":"75"
               },
               {
                  "number":2,
                  "score":"--"
               }
            ],
            "today":"-",
            "thru":"7:41 PM"
         },
         {
            "name":"Danny Willett",
            "rounds":[
               {
                  "number":1,
                  "score":"75"
               },
               {
                  "number":2,
                  "score":"--"
               }
            ],
            "today":"-",
            "thru":"7:41 PM"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My models to parse the code starts from the user class and populates from within:

```
class User {
  String name;
  List<Golfer> golfers;

  User({@required this.name,
        @required this.golfers});

  static User fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(name: json["name"],
                golfers: json["golfers"].map((golfer) => Golfer.fromJson(golfer)).toList());
  }
}

class Golfer {
  String name;
  List<Round> rounds;
  String today;
  String thru;

  String score(int roundNumber) {
    return rounds[roundNumber].score;
  }

  Golfer({@required this.name,
          @required this.rounds,
          @required this.today,
          @required this.thru});

  static Golfer fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Golfer(name: json["name"],
                  rounds: json["rounds"].map((round) => Round.fromJson(round)).toList(),
                  today: json["today"].toString(),
                  thru: json["thru"].toString());
  }
}

class Round {
  String number;
  String score;

  Round({@required this.number,
         @required this.score});

  static Round fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Round(number: json["number"].toString(),
                 score: json["score"].toString());
  }
}
```

But when i call `json.decode(response.body)).map((user) => User.fromJson(user)).toList()` i get the following error `expected a value of type 'List<Round>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'`
i cant see where i am going wrong and im sure its simple but i just cant see it.

The error is so specific too but i cant seem to parse the rounds properly for some reason.

The link to the json is [here](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=i6hRck8yiKJEHNCEO3-56h75BCaPGuCoWs3XP7MxiJMJQao1gM0k45g0lw00mi7n1KBFhFrQXBpHfPyQSNJ3BYlyzC5KgOuVm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnOhOSJSAwrH5ak82UtcKUs5QctgwfSTfIOJo26eh_nJZ2mi-_HGeDQc9HfQUPyKqTDOmbnRGq-tk&lib=Meqy2T-lYyzfQfXH-Sqlk20wI2BjkVmPv)

Comment: try to use this tool to generate models https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try defining generic types when converting `toList()`

e.g.
replace

```
rounds: json["rounds"].map((round) => Round.fromJson(round)).toList(),
```

with

```
rounds: json["rounds"].map<Round>((round) => Round.fromJson(round)).toList(),
```

and

```
golfers: json["golfers"].map((golfer) => Golfer.fromJson(golfer)).toList()
```

with

```
golfers: json["golfers"].map<Golfer>((golfer) => Golfer.fromJson(golfer)).toList()
```